# PHP json_decode does not work

Tags: php, json

I am trying the following code to receive JSON . However the decode does not give a result. It works for a copy of the same string with escape slashes.

```
<?php
$input = file_get_contents('php://input');
logToFile("post.txt",$input);
#Output: {"id":"id1","model":"model1","version":"v1","software":["s1","s2","s3"]}

$data = json_decode($input,true);
logToFile("post.txt",$data['version']);
#Output:Empty result

### Works
$data1 = json_decode("{\"id\":\"id1\",\"model\":\"model1\",\"version\":\"v1\",\"software\":[\"s1\",\"s2\",\"s3\"]}",true);
logToFile("post.txt",$data1['version']);
#Output:v1

function logToFile($filename,$msg)
{
  $fd=fopen($filename,"a");
  $str="[".date("Y/m/d h:i:s")."]".$msg;
  fwrite($fd,$str."\n");
  fclose($fd);
}
?>
```

I am using PHP 5.4. So it's not a problem in magic quotes. Any help?

Comment: What is `var_dump($data)`?

Comment: try calling  `echo json_last_error_msg ()` after your json_decode.

Comment: $input is received from a HTTP POST, it's shown in #Output line

Comment: @kevinamadeus: $var_dump give null.

Comment: just a WAG but try doing `$data = json_decode(trim($input),true);`

Comment: @Suranga It's not the quotes. When you are reading the data from 'php://input' something else is put into $input, that's why json_decode breaks

Comment: @user4035 Got it var_dump($input) had an extra string. It was not shown when $input was written to the file. Removed the string and it's working fine. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the problem is with the json_decode.

```
$input = '{"id":"id1","model":"model1","version":"v1","software":["s1","s2","s3"]}';
$data = json_decode($input,true);
echo $data['version'];
```

Works fine.

So if you go:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r( $input );
echo "</pre>";
```

After you get the $input from the file. Does it appear OK ?

Comment: It was ok in the file. But when I check the var_dump($input) it was like software+json string. The additional software term was sent by the client. It was removed and now it's working fine.